# Merging multiple point shapefiles that have same coordinates but different years

Tags: arcgis-pro, merge, spatial-join, time-series

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have 35 shapefiles of point data, with each layer representing a different year of data collection.  Each layer has points with the same coordinates.  I want to bring these layers together in order to export a single attribute table with the time series data.

Would a spatial join or a merge be the appropriate tool?

Is there a way to bring all 35 layers together at once?

Comment: Is the year or date a column in the attribute table?

Comment: Trying Spatial Join or Merge is faster than getting an answer. Do you want duplicate points in each location or just one point with "35 attributes"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rotation and translation matrix to transfer every feature points to the first set.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If there is a unique key in the attribute table for each location that is common across the shapefiles, the easiest way to merge these is to use the [Add Join](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/tool-reference/data-management/add-join.htm) tool to join pairs of files using that key. If there is not a unique key, then a [Spatial Join](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) is appropriate. If the locations are truly identical, then setting Match Option to "Are identical to" should work. Otherwise, you may have to use "Closest." The Merge tool would not be appropriate because it simply combines all features from the input shapefiles into a single file, but does not alter/join those features.

You will need to loop over the shapefiles using ArcPy or an iterator in ModelBuilder to join all 35 files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the Union-tool. With Arcpro advanced you can add multiple shapes at once.